# How can I determine the encryption used by knowing input and result?

Tags: encryption, hash, brute-force

Is it possible to determine the encryption or hash used if I know the original input and final output? There is a similar post here: [Determine encoding/hashing methods used based on knowing the input and output only?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23450/determine-encoding-hashing-methods-used-based-on-knowing-the-input-and-output-on)
However I feel it is lacking, I mean there must be a way. Is there a program that could take the input and brute-force common encryption types til it matches the output?

Some how I go from this: `974332` (one variable changed to protect identity)

To this: `1ddae068-944d-454d-9ecd-0cbe98f81463` (one variable changed to protect identity)

There most be some algorithm used to but I do not know it and I want to find out. I could collect as many of these samples as I need but without the algorithm I have no way of knowing how I get from point A to point B.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want... Like the answers on that question you linked to suggest, there is no good way to do it...

Comment: What about brute forcing like my post suggests, is that not possible?

Comment: @user26457 Sure, you can brute force to your heart's content. The answer is the same as what you pointed to, though, unless you can point to something more specific to ask. Particular since you posted something UUID formatted, I can't figure what it came from.