# What type of encryption or hasing is used?

Tags: passwords

How to determine what type encryption or hashing is used for the following or 6760bb6a0b7468ac3549670e86450c07f424b3b021b983e820eb701b481d5f75  and how to decode it?

Comment: Based on the length it could be MD5 (128 bit). But it might be something else too. Possible duplicate of [Determine encoding/hashing methods used based on knowing the input and output only?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23450/determine-encoding-hashing-methods-used-based-on-knowing-the-input-and-output-on),[How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used).

Comment: Considering it's 64 characters in length, it could be SHA256. Hashes are one way functions and can not be decoded.